# Unable to find provider assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer'. Ensure the name is correct and it's referenced by the project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, sql-server-2019, entity-framework-core-3.1

Please can you tell me how I solve this problem?

Code to scaffold:

```
scaffold-dbcontext "server=.\DESKTOP-UO195S8; database=BooksDB; integrated security=false;User ID=sa;Password=shvi" 
         Microsoft.EntityFrameworkcore.sqlserver -OutputDir models
```

Comment: Namespace is Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer i believe with capital letter for the S
Example (works on my machine) Scaffold-DbContext "Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database={mydbname};Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models

Comment: I tried this solution but it didn't work and same problem   (Unable to find provider assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer'. Ensure the name is correct and it's referenced by the project.)

Comment: the problem with (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer) package When I try to download this package I get the same error message as before

Comment: A few things i can see that might be the problem is: If you use the package manager you have not set the target project correct, Something wens wrong with installing the package so check if it is in the .csproj you can run a nuget restore maybe?

Comment: *When I try to download this package* -- Please make this very clear. Do you mean that you *installed* the package by the `add package`command?

Comment: package its doesn't exist in csproj  I tried to install it by NuGet Shortly after starting the installation, I get the same error (Unable to find provider assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer'. Ensure the name is correct and it's referenced by the project.)

Comment: You *tried*. Again, please be crystal clear. Did you install it *successfully*?

Comment: oh dear Gert sorry No I didn't  it it show the same Error ? (Unable to find provider assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer'. Ensure the name is correct and it's referenced by the project)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SHORT SOLUTION: downgrade to version 3.1.15 of everything of .net core 3.1 assemblies (**2022 update**: you also may need to upgrade to the latest version available)

EXPLANATION: You should check if you have the same version of `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design` as you current version of `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`. For some unknown reasons, the last stable version of `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design` is `3.1.15` while the default stable version of `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` is currently `3.1.18` (see picture 1)

Therefore, when you run the scolding command, it tries to install a version which really is not compatible with the versions inside your project(possibly)

[image: stable Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design]

Vs

[image: stable Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer]

Downgrading to 3.1.15 and bob is your uncle